# CVXPY: How to maximize dot product of two vectors

Tags: python, optimization, array-broadcasting, portfolio, cvxpy

Suppose we have three features and 252 samples per each feature. Here, features are returns of three different stocks. The goal is to maximize the total return, i,e,

[image]
[image]

My question is how to define this objective function inside a `CVXpy` optimization problem?

The procedural view of the program should be look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cvx;

return1 = np.random.normal(loc=0.05, scale=0.25, size=252)
return2 = np.random.normal(loc=0.01, scale=0.2, size=252)
return3 = np.random.normal(loc= -0.05, scale=0.15, size=252)
returns = np.array([return1, return2, return3])

# number of stocks m is number of rows of returns
m = returns.shape[0]

# x variables (to be found with optimization)
x = cvx.Variable(m)

# portfolio return
portfolio_return = cvx.multiply(returns, x)

#objective function
objective = cvx.Minimize(-portfolio_return)

#constraints
constraints = [x >= 0, sum(x) == 1]

#use cvxpy to solve the objective
cvx.Problem(objective, constraints).solve()

#retrieve the weights of the optimized portfolio
x_values = x.value

print(x_values)
```

However, it returns an error:

```
ValueError: Cannot broadcast dimensions  (3, 252) (3,)
```

When we represent x as `x = cvx.Variable(shape=(m,1))` we get another error

```
ValueError: The 'minimize' objective must resolve to a scalar.
```

Python Version: 3.8.8

CVXPY Version: 1.1.12

Comment: Your `returns` is a matrix. It should be a vector (the same length as x).

Comment: Thank you for comment +1; please see the answer posted.

Comment: @sci9, just found this https://www.javacodexamples.com/examples/cvxpy-how-to-maximize-dot-product-of-two-vectors. Was it posted by you? Or is this a case of blatant plagiarism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to cvxpy community, I've reformulated the problem and it now runs without any error.

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cvx;
return1 = np.random.normal(loc=0.05, scale=0.25, size=252)
return2 = np.random.normal(loc=0.01, scale=0.2, size=252)
return3 = np.random.normal(loc= -0.05, scale=0.15, size=252)
returns = np.array([return1, return2, return3])
m = returns.shape[0]
cov = np.cov(returns)
x = cvx.Variable(m)
portfolio_return = returns.mean(axis=1)
objective = cvx.Maximize(x @ portfolio_return)
constraints = [x >= 0, sum(x) == 1]
cvx.Problem(objective, constraints).solve()
x_values = x.value
x_values.round(2)
```